# Extracting from BS4 and storing as list elements in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have extracted data wrapped within multiple HTML p tags from a webpage using BeautifulSoup4. I have stored all of the extracted data in a list. But I want each of the extracted data as separate list elements separated by a comma.

HTML content structure:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <p>
        <span class="TextRun">
          <span class="NormalTextrun"> Data 1 </span>
        </span>
      </p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <p>
        <span class="TextRun">
          <span class="NormalTextrun"> Data 2 </span>
        </span>
      </p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <p>
        <span class="TextRun">
          <span class="NormalTextrun"> Data 3 </span>
        </span>
      </p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Code to extract:

```
for data in elem.find_all('span', class_="TextRun"):
    data = ''.join([' '.join(item.text.split()) for item in elem.select(".NormalTextRun")])
    data = data.replace(u'\xa0', '')
    events_parsed_thisweek.append(data)
    print (events_parsed_thisweek)
```

Current output: 
[Data1Data2Data3]

Expected output:
[Data1, Data2, Data3]

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what @Sagun Shrestha suggest works. To deal with it more detailly like the inner `span` and the extra spaces. Maybe you should try:

```
data = [s.text.strip() for s in b.find_all('span', class_='NormalTextrun')]
print(data)
```

If you specifically want the string output without the quotation marks. You can try this:

```
data = [s.text.strip() for s in b.find_all('span', class_='NormalTextrun')]
print('[', ', '.join(data), ']', sep='')
```

Hope it's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = [x.text.strip() for x in elem.find_all('span', {'class': 'NormalTextrun'})]
```

Printing data will give you: `['Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3']`

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem

```
data = [x.text for x in elem.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'TextRun'})]
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives the correct output:

```
data = [ele.text for ele in soup.find_all('span', {'class':'NormalTextrun'})]
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[' Data 1 ', ' Data 2 ', ' Data 3 ']
```